# Tableview cell multiple check mark selection to add cell data into single array Swift 4.2?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

My scenario, I have loaded my `JSON` data into `tableView` with help of `codable`. Here, I have added my `tableView` cell `multiple` check mark select and `deselect`. Now, If I am selecting tableView cell I can able to get `cell` data but I want to add within one `array`, same if I am unselecting cell It should `remove` from the array. Selected cell data I am moving to another `ViewController`. I would like to know how to do that.

My Code

```
// method to run when table view cell is tapped
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("You tapped cell number \(indexPath.row).")

        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath) {
            if cell.accessoryType == .checkmark {
                cell.accessoryType = .none
            } else {
                cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
                let item = users[indexPath.row]
                print(item) // here printing cell selection data 
            }
        }
    }
```

My Cell Selection current output

```
You tapped cell number 1.
User(userId: "121”, active: 1, name: example_table.Name(firstname: "jack", lastname: "m"))
You tapped cell number 2.
User(userId: "122”, active: 1, name: example_table.Name(firstname: “rose”, lastname: “h”))
You tapped cell number 3.
User(userId: "123”, active: 1, name: example_table.Name(firstname: “makj”, lastname: “i”))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
var selectedArr = [Item]()
var users = [Item]()

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("You tapped cell number \(indexPath.row).")
    let item = users[indexPath.row]
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) { // you can also omit the if let and force-unwrap as in this case cell will never be nil 
        if cell.accessoryType == .checkmark {
            cell.accessoryType =  .none
            selectedArr.remove(where:{ $0 == item })
        } else {
            cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
            selectedArr.append(item)
        }
    }
}
```

Then inside `cellForRowAt`

```
let cell = ////
let item = users[indexPath.row]
cell.accessoryType = selectedArr.contains(item) ? .checkmark : .none
```

Also make sure model named `Item` conforms to `Equatable`

---

given

```
  for (index, element) in item.enumerated() { 
     print("Item \(index): \(element)")
  }
```

that gives

> Item 0: 121, Item 1: 122, Item 2: 123

Then it's an array of Ints , so do

```
 let res = item.map{ "\($0)" }.joined(separator: ",")
```

Comment: I can able to get the values like Item 0: 121,
Item 1: 122,
Item 2: 123, using for (index, element) in item.enumerated() {
            print("Item \(index): \(element),")
        } Now how to change like id = 121,122,123 @Sh_Khan

Answer (score 0):

So it sounds like you want to be able to have an array that contains all of the selected Users. Then what you would do is have an array like this instantiated in the class declaration:

```
var users:[Users] = []
```

Now what you should be doing is leveraging swift's protocols in order to handle the heavy lifting for you; meaning, when removing a previously selected user from the Users array, you shouldn't need a for loop, but something more familiar: contains.

```
extension User: Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: User, rhs: User) -> Bool {
        return lhs.userId == rhs.userId
    }
}
```

So now you can call this when removing or adding, for example:

```
var thisUser = User(userId: "123”, active: 1, name: example_table.Name(firstname: “makj”, lastname: “i”))

if users.contains(thisUser) {
    users.removeAtIndex(users.indexOf(thisUser))
} else {
    //Add the user to the array here for example
    users.append(thisUser)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use an extra array, add the *selected* information to your model.

```
struct User : Codable {

    var isSelected = false
    // ... other members

}
```

Assuming the data source array is declared as `users`, set the checkmark depending on the `isSelected` value in `cellForRowAt`

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
    let user = users[indexPath.row]
    cell.accessoryType = user.isSelected ? .checkmark : .none

    ... 
}
```

In `didSelectRowAt` just toggle `isSelected` and reload the row

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    users[indexPath.row].isSelected.toggle()
    tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
}
```

To get all selected users just `filter` the array

```
let selectedUsers = users.filter{ $0.isSelected }
```